# Unable to fetch user data by using tiktok-scraper npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, web-scraping, tiktok

I have used [tiktok-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiktok-scraper) for getting any public TikTok users data. It was working fine recently and I was able to get the required data but suddenly it stopped working and started giving this error:

`Error: Can't extract user metadata from the HTML page. Make sure that the user does exist and try to use proxy`

The module that I have used is `.getUserProfileInfo('USERNAME', options)` without using any `options`. Earlier I was able to get user details by just passing the `username`.

[Someone has suggested](https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper/issues/437#issuecomment-816689190) to try using the `cookie "sessionid_ss"` in the `sessionList` option but I don't know where can I get this value from.

It would be great if someone can guide in this regard to get any public TikTok users' details based on the username.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this @Muhammad Rizwan. I'm also facing the same issue. Looking forward to the responses